# Check to Exit Program before User Input is Stored

Tags: java, do-while, bufferedwriter

I have a nearly finished program. Only problem is when the user enters "exit" to kill the program, the word "exit" is written to the file "quotes.txt" at the end. How do I get the program to check for "exit" first and not write it into "quotes.txt"?

Here is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    final Formatter fo;
    BufferedWriter bw = null;
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("quotes.txt"));
    String input = "";
    String line;

    File quotesFile = new File("quotes.txt");

    if (quotesFile.exists()) {
        System.out.println(quotesFile.getName() + " exists.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("THIS DOES NOT EXIST.");
    }

    try {
        fo = new Formatter("quotes.txt");
        System.out.println("File created or found.");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("You have an error.");
    }

    do {
        try {
            Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

            if (!input.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")) {

                System.out.println("Enter your text(Type 'exit' to close program.): ");
                bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(quotesFile, true));
                input = kb.nextLine();
                bw.write(input);
                bw.newLine();
                bw.close();
                System.out.println("Entry added.\n");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error.");
        }
    } while (!input.equalsIgnoreCase("exit"));

    System.out.println("Results: ");

    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Instead of a do-while loop make a while loop. Also you do not need to create a new BufferedWriter every time in the loop. Also the input may contain spaces and/or newline chars, so you should try to compare input.trim().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check what the input is before writing it to the file.

```
            System.out.println("Enter your text(Type 'exit' to close program.): ");
            bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(quotesFile, true));
            input = kb.nextLine();
            if(!input.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")) {
                bw.write(input);
                bw.newLine();
                bw.close();
                System.out.println("Entry added.\n");
            }
       }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could only instanciate your Scanner and writer once. The key of the problem is that you check the input after the test. Note that you duplicated tests: one in the `if`, one other in the `while`. I'd suggest you this algorithm:

```
Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
input = kb.nextLine();

while (!input.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Enter your text(Type 'exit' to close program.): ");
        bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(quotesFile, true));
        bw.write(input);
        bw.newLine();
        bw.close();
        System.out.println("Entry added.\n");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error.");
    }
    input = kb.nextLine();
}
```

Note that `do...while` do not respond best to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for providing another way instead of do-while. I've heard using do-while isn't the best practice if you can avoid it.

Comment: You're welcome! Just take care of your resulting script, I saw you accepted previous answer but check how you open/close your writer: when you open one, shoud (have to) close it. A good practice for this is to place in your case `bw.close();` in a `finally` block after your `catch`. More over, you could open the Writer outside the loop and close it only after. Good luck!